# How to determine if one number is within a certain range of another

Tags: java

I would like to determine if one number is within a certain range of another number.

For instance, if I have the number `50`, and then I input the number `i`, I would like to be able to determine if `i` is within 10 digits of `50`. In other words, is `i` in the range of 40 to 49 or 51 to 60.  How would I go about doing that?

Comment: I say, "go for it!", and please do let us know if you succeed. If later you have an *answerable* question about your attempt, please come back, show your code attempt, and ask your *specific* question about just what confuses you or what errors you might be seeing. Otherwise, good luck in your endeavor!

Comment: Please do explain to me how my question is not answerable? I love the people on here that already know everything and just like to belittle those of us that are trying to learn something.

Comment: I've got nothing against folks trying to learn, but at least show your attempt, or is that asking too much of you? Else you're only cheating yourself.

Comment: I don't have an attempt. I have been trying to write it out on paper but so far I haven't come up with anything that makes sense.

Comment: If you've put in effort solving the question, any effort, you should include that with your question. Else, how will we know where exactly you might be stuck? Else how will we know what you've tried or what *exactly* confuses you about a subject? Else the question is little more than a homework or work dump.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take the absolute value of the difference and check whether it is less than 10, or you can skip the absolute value part and simply test whether the difference is between -10 and 10 (and not zero, if you want to exclude equality).

Comment: `if(50-i >= -10 && 50-i <=10){ //do my thing? }`

Comment: @WeVie - Exactly. For style points, I'd recommend storing `50-i` in a variable and test the variable's value. That would avoid having to do the calculation twice. (A trivial savings in this case, but good form in general, all else being equal.)